# Some of tensorflow GPU OpKernel compute by eigen device without stream sync, is that buggy?

Tags: tensorflow

from gpu_device.cc

`// NOTE(tucker): We need to discriminate between Eigen GPU
   // operations and all others.  If an operation is Eigen
   // implemented (or otherwise tries to launch a cuda kernel
   // directly), we need to establish a stacked-scoped environment
   // that directs it to execute on the proper device.  Otherwise we
   // expect the Op to use StreamExecutor directly and correctly.  The
   // way we make this discrimination is quite hacky: At the moment
   // the only non-Eigen GPU Op is the recv-op, which is known to be
   // asynchronous.`

and gpu_device only waits when different context. (sync_every_op is false)

But in argmax_op.h, for example,

```
template <typename Device, typename T>
struct ArgMin {
#define DECLARE_COMPUTE_SPEC(Dims)                                     \
EIGEN_ALWAYS_INLINE static void Reduce##Dims(                        \
const Device& d, typename TTypes<T, Dims>::ConstTensor input,    \
const int32 dimension,                                           \
typename TTypes<int64, Dims - 1>::Tensor output) {               \
output.device(d) = input.argmin(dimension).template cast<int64>(); \
}
```

use device compute directly. Is that correct?

Comment: I missed something. cuda stream is passed to eigen device. so there's no problem.

Comment: Sorry but, I have some questions in your code. What does mean output.device(d) = ~...? Is that means computing rhs operation in device d?

Answer (score 1):

I missed something. cuda stream is passed to eigen device. so there's no problem